# How to configure port when create copy of Docker container

Tags: docker

I have Docker container `cont1` on remote server, and I can connect to Jupyter notebook on it with ssh.
I try to make "copy" of that container with:

- `docker commit imagename`
- `docker run -d --name cont2 -p 0.0.0.0:9999:9999/tcp imagename`

I can connect to port 9999 with ssh, but I cant open Jupyter in browser.
`Docker ps` shows:

```
name    PORTS
cont1   0.0.0.0:8888:8888->8888/tcp
cont2   8888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9999->9999/tcp
```

I think problem is that `cont2` has 2 port settings. How can I run second container correctly?
According to `ps -ef | grep python`, jupyter is running on `cont2`

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  Among other things, it loses some metadata like the command the underlying base image was supposed to run, and if you need to update the original image (say, for a critical security fix) you're probably not going to remember what commands you manually ran in the container.  What image did you run for the original container, and can you `docker run` a new container off that same image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter runs on 8888 port by default, so run should be like

`docker run -d --name cont2 -p 0.0.0.0:9999:8888/tcp imagename`